# Any way of making matrix searching and comparing elements within matrixes more pythonic?

Tags: python, matrix

I'd like to compare matrix elements. This method works, but it's a pain to write.

```
matrix = [[0,1],[2,1],[3,2],[4,5]]
def matrixElementsSum(matrix):
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
```

I know you can write

```
matrix = [[0,1],[2,1],[3,2],[4,5]]
def matrixElementsSum(matrix):
    for i in matrix:
        for j in i:
```

And get the individual elements of the lists within the matrix.

However I'd like to compare `matrix[0][0]` with `matrix[0][1]` and `matrix[0][2]`.

Both methods essentially do the same thing, but the first one allows you to move around within the matrix, while the second method doesn't.

Are there better ways of moving within matrixes? Can it be done in one line instead of two?

**Edit:**

**For those who asked, the longer form version of this problem is taking a matrix such as:**

```
[0,1,3,4,0]
[1,2,0,4,1]
[1,0,0,4,4]
```

**and only adding together the numbers that are positive, and not located beneath a 0.**

It should only add these numbers:

```
[x,1,3,4,x]
[x,2,x,4,x]
[x,x,x,4,x]
```

I figured, by going through it, you could remove the entire column below as you go through row by row.

first iteration becomes:

```
[1,3,4]
[2,x,4]
[x,x,4]
```

second:

```
[1,3,4]
[2,4]
[x,4]
```

and third becomes:

```
[1,3,4]
[2,4]
[4]
```

This method seems like it would work with any size matrix and provide an answer.

In order to iterate that way, you'd need to take matrix location `[0][0]` and then iterate through it row by row, removing `[1][0]` and `[2][0]`. And do that over and over. The reason why I don't want to use the for `i in matrix` and `for j in i` method is because variables `j` and `i` will only return the item within the matrix location, rather than the matrix location itself which can then be used to call the item within the location or can be operated upon to retrieve values below it.

There may be a better method to solve this problem, which is interesting to me, however, the original question is just as interesting to me. So if you read through this problem and only answer how to do it better, keep in mind that the original question is still a serious stumbling block for me at this time and understanding it will help me solve more problems in the future.

Additionally, I can't quite figure out how to delete items from a matrix. using `del matrix[i][j]` gives me `out of range` errors. .pop() and .remove() I can't figure out how to use either. It seems like numpy is the way to go for more complex list and matrix operations?

**Edit again:**

Solved the problem but didn't really learn the answer to the initial question yet.

This was the most elegant solution I've seen:

```
def matrixElementsSum(matrix):
    t = 0
    for c in zip(*matrix):
        for r in c:
            if r == 0:
                break
            t += r
    return t
```

Comment: What is your final goal? Depending on what you want to do, there are shortcuts.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You can move around a matrix at will through any combination of indices. Your nested `for` loops just go through every single element.

Comment: In pure Python there isn't much better but [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) is made for this.

Comment: are you perhaps looking for enumerate? https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate

Comment: Edit above that may help understand what I'm looking for